# Creating grammars for lexical analyzer

Tags: lexical-analysis, lexical

I am trying to create a lexical analyzer for a given language. Can't write grammar rules correctly. My task is

> The input language contains conditional statements `if ... then ... else` and `if ... then`, separated by a symbol `;` (semicolon). Condition statements contain identifiers, comparison signs `<,>, =`, hexadecimal numbers, sign assignments (`:=`). Consider the sequence as hexadecimal numbers digits and symbols `a, b, c, d, e, f` starting with a digit (for example, 89, 45ac, 0abc )

I got these rules:

```
S -> if E then S else S; S | if E then S; S | if E then S else S | if E then S | I := E 
E -> H | E > H | E < H | E = H
I -> LLL
H -> DHL | DL | DH |D
L -> a | b | c | d | e | f
D -> 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
```

Is the rule (`H -> DHL | DL | D | DH`) for determining hexadecimal numbers set correctly? Are the rest of the rules correct?

Comment: A simpler way of writing the hexadecimal number rule is `H -> D | HD | HL`. But lexical analysers in practice usually use regular expressions, which would be something like `[0-9][0-9a-f]*`. The lexical analyser does not analyse the syntactic structure (in the most usual parser architecture); that's done with a syntactic parser, which does use BNF.

Comment: @rici, yes,I heard that in some compilers, lexical analysis occurs in the syntactic. But my task is process a stream of tokens in a syntax analyzer, where tokens are generated in a lexical analyzer. Thanks for you answer